# MongoDB $regex query for "end with" particular char

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I am not able to remove object from an array named `Matrix` for a Key match

```
 BasicDBObject where = new BasicDBObject();
    where.put("INSTITUTION_ID", instid);
    where.put("RuleID", ruleid);

    BasicDBObject obj1 = new BasicDBObject();
    obj1.put("Matrix.Key",new BasicDBObject("$regex","/"+json.getString("Code")+"$/"));

collection.update(where,new BasicDBObject("$pull", obj1));
```

The code above is not removing object from array. The structure of the array can be found below

```
"Matrix" : [
        {
            "Key" : "6M",
            "value" : "Queue"
        },
        {
            "Key" : "6N",
            "value" : "Queue"
        },
        {
            "Key" : "6O",
            "value" : "Queue"
        }]
```

Comment: The `/` regex delimiters are specific to JavaScript. Try removing them so that it's just `("$regex", json.getString("Code")+"$")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Command-line client

I suggest that before writing queries in Java notation, you first test them in the `mongo` console, with the regular JavaScript syntax. The following query works for me.

#### Data

```
db.matrix.insert(
{
    INSTITUTION_ID: 1,
    RuleID: 2,
    Matrix: [
        {
            "Key": "6M",
            "value": "Queue"
        },
        {
            "Key": "6N",
            "value": "Queue"
        },
        {
            "Key": "6O",
            "value": "Queue"
        }
    ]
})
```

#### Query

```
db.matrix.update(
{
    INSTITUTION_ID: 1,
    RuleID: 2,
},
{
    $pull:
    {
        Matrix:
        {
            Key:
            {
                $regex: /M$/
            }
        }
    }
})
```

#### Data after the update

```
{
    "INSTITUTION_ID" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "RuleID" : 2.0000000000000000,
    "Matrix" : [ 
        {
            "Key" : "6N",
            "value" : "Queue"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "6O",
            "value" : "Queue"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Java

I am not sure how this update query should be represented in Java, but try this:

```
BasicDBObject where =
    new BasicDBObject()
        .put("INSTITUTION_ID", instid);
        .put("RuleID", ruleid);

BasicDBObject update =
    new BasicDBObject("$pull",
        new BasicDBObject("Matrix",
            new BasicDBObject("Key",
                new BasicDBObject("$regex",
                    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(json.getString("Code") + "$")))));

collection.update(where, update);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro,  i also tried the same solution in Mongo Shell and that is working but Java code is not able to update Document.

Comment: @sumitchoudhary have you tried it with my Java code?

Comment: Yes, I am still facing the same issue.its not removing the object from array.

Comment: @sumitchoudhary I have update my answer to use  `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile` instead of a raw string. Try the code now and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro, now its working. but can you explain more about it.

Comment: @sumitchoudhary well, something was wrong with the regex string you were passing. Probably, the forward slashes needed to be removed. To be on the safe side, I decided to pass a regex object instead, to ensure that we're passing something valid.